# For loop syntax and running a script twice

Tags: r, for-loop

Okay, I think this might have a simple answer / solution but I'm drawing a blank. Maybe I don't understand something fundamental that I should. If I have a script in R that does literally anything, and want to have it run twice, couldn't I just slap a for loop around it like this:

```
for(i in 1:2){
    R script goes here
}
```

I know that usually the for loops I write have the `i` variable changing with every iteration (and that `i` variable is inside the loop too). So if this isn't working, could part of the problem be that I don't have anything inside the loop that is using `i`?

**EDIT:** I don't think my question was clearly written. Let me say it this way as well. If I had a for loop that simply counted 1 to 100, I could write it like this.

```
for (i in 1:100){
    print(i)
}
```

However, I could also make the loop like this:

```
for (i in 1:100){
    print(2)
}
```

Which would, instead of counting, print the number 2, 100 times.

Now I have a much more complicated script that executes a batch file, then connects to SQL server to drop data into several databases. I don't see why it would make a difference to simply replace `print(2)` with my script.

The script works perfectly without the for loop, but once that is included it breaks. Perhaps this is more complex than simply how the loop is implemented and I should post a different question going into further detail.

Comment: Yes, it is easy to validate. Try `for(i in 1:2) print(sample(1e5, 1))`, for instance

Comment: If you intend to save the output rather than just executing it for side effects like printing or plotting, you'll need some extra care. Consider `replicate`.

Comment: I'm wondering if I didn't write my question clear. I'm not printing anything. I'll make an edit to hopefully clear it up.

Comment: Yes, that will in theory work. In practice it may depend on the R code you are running. For instance, if you are reading from a table in the DB and then dropping the table, the next time you won't be able to read again from the table. This obviously would have nothing to do with the for loop, but it's not possible to know unless 1) we see the script 2) you tell us what error you are getting.

Comment: Right, I thought it might be difficult to extrapolate a simple idea out to a complex script. The for loop is literally around the entire script though. (except a `setwd()` and several `library()`). I thought it would be simple enough to simply for the script to automatically run twice.